# Sum using two filter variables

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I have a ledger sheet that was set up to record costs for a single project.  We've added a project column so we can track more than one project so every entry (row) now is identified per project. I'm already running some `SUMIF` functions to total a column if another column matches a criteria, but I now need to add in another criterion...

For example:

My existing formula sums column J where column E = "sometext"

```
=Sumif(Ledger!$E$7:$E$900, "Amberon", Ledger!$J$7:$J$900)
```

How can I expand this to sum only when two columns match?

My newly added project identifier is column `Ledger!$A$7:$A$900`

Ideally, I'll only have one set of sum values but will select which project they apply to based on the value in a cell with a picker (List of projects).

I've read about `SUMIFS` but can't seem to understand the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A17, B1:B17, "Dragon",
                C1:C17, "Kate")
```

[image: 6]